# C macro or GCC directive to consume next code statement

Tags: c, gcc, macros, directive, pragma

Is there a C macro, a GCC directive or pragma, to consume the next code statement following the macro, without explicitly passing it as an argument to the macro?

Something like this:

```
#define CONSUME_NEXT_IF(a) if (a) { (<next>) } else;
```

And I would use it as:

```
CONSUME_NEXT_IF(a) stmt1;
```

And expect it to expand to:

```
  if (a) stmt1; 
  else;
```

I am using an `if` statement here just as an example. The conditional statement isn't the point, rather the ability to consume `stmt1` by the macro without actually passing it as an argument.

Comment: `(a) &&` should do.

Comment: @EOF, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Mhh, actually it won't always work. You'd need to make sure `stmt1` is always parenthesized or doesn't contain any operator of lower precedence than `&&`.

Comment: Can you explain why - other than obfuscating code - you would seek to do this?

Comment: @Peter Mainly syntax sugar. We have a relatively huge code base, and want to achieve a similar effect to annotations, without extensively messing with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define CONSUME_NEXT_IF(a) if (!(a)) {} else
```

will achieve the effect of only executing the "next statement" (between use of the macro and next `;`) if `a` is `true` (or non-zero).   If you have suitable constraints on what type of expression `a` is, you might be able to remove the `()` on `(a)`.

Personally, although you've explained in comments that you want a similar effect to annotations, I consider this will introduce more maintenance concerns - including code obfuscation - than it alleviates.   Particularly if it interacts with other macros being used in `a` or `stmt1`.

And, of course, it would be necessary to modify your "large code base" to use the macro.

This also leaves dead code in your executable - it doesn't stop code for `stmt1` being emitted to the executable (unless `a` has a fixed compile-time value, and your compiler has capability to detect and optimise code in such circumstances).    Therefore such a construct will mean you cannot satisfy requirements of several assurance standards that require prevention of dead code.

Comment: If you're that worried about code-golfing this, why not `#define CONSUME_NEXT_IF(a) if(!(a)); else` to save a few character, rather than risk operator precedence woes by removing parentheses?